# Report filter based on chatter feed

Tags: reporting, chatter

I would like to create a report filter that is something like "Every contact with a Chatter post including [conference name]" Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?   Are you conisderig using only standard features or custom coding/programming?

Comment: I was able to create a report type that was "Contacts with Chatter Posts" that was able to make it work. It limits me to the number of different objects I can have in a report, but in general it is very helpful.